# When is the weak limit of operators invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

Suppose $T_i$ are invertible operators in $L^{2}(X)$ for X a Lebesgue Probability Space.

Is the following true?

> **1.** If the $T_i$ converge weakly to $S$, then $S$ is not necessarily invertible.
>
> **2.** If the $T_i$ converge weakly to $S$ and the $T_i$ commute with each other, then $S$ is invertible and in fact $T_i^{-1}$ converges weakly to $S^{-1}$.

I have already posted this question in ergodic theory section but I didn't have any answers so far. I restated it here in functional analytic point of view. ( [Weak convergence of finite measure preserving transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829992/weak-convergence-of-finite-measure-preserving-transformations))